# Unity / Calling Method from another GameObject is not working, but only in life cycle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a DontDestroyOnLoad Game Object in Scene, and in that Game Object I am trying to call a method after Scene change. The Method is executing fine, but I can't access to the Game Object in current Scene. With some painful time, I found a way to call method. It was making a flag in Update function. How can I fix it to call method right?

It is my DontDestroyOnLoad Method

```
private void onEnterLobbySucceed(SocketIOResponse data)
{
    Util.logData<DataOnEnterLobbySucceed>(data);
    LobbyManager manager = (LobbyManager)this.currentManager;
    manager.onEnterLobbySucceed();
}
```

And this is LobbyManager's method

```
private void Update()
{
    if(this._lobbyEnterSucceed == true)
    {
        this._onEnterLobbySucceed(); // <-- This is working.
        this._lobbyEnterSucceed = false;
    }
}
public void onEnterLobbySucceed()
{
    Debug.Log("Enter Lobby Succeed!");
    this._lobbyEnterSucceed = true;
    this._onEnterLobbySucceed(); // <-- This is not working.
}
public void _onEnterLobbySucceed()
{
    Destroy(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GrayLayer"));
    Destroy(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Loading"));
    string userName = PlayerDataContainer.getInstance().getPlayerData().name;
    NameField.GetComponent<TMP_Text>().text = userName;
}
```

Comment: Please be careful not to tag unrelated programming languages (e.g. UnityScript). I've removed that tag for you.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is some execution order problem. Maybe some GameObjects you're trying to access is not yet instantiated.

Comment: @CristianoSchiaffella But I'm sure that I executed those methods after Instantiate. Wouldn't be there any other clue??

Comment: Solve this. Process was not on Main Thread.